# Recursion Logarithm to find the highest integer(n) in the form = (2)^n, closest to another integer x

Tags: java, recursion

The result I am expecting to see: for example
partition(603=1+2+8+16+64+512)
As you can see, it is in powers of 2. I cant not seem to figure out whats wrong.

```
    static String partition (int n){
            int a=0;
            if (n<=1)
                return String.valueOf(n);
            while ((int)Math.pow(2, a)<=n)
                a++;

            return partition(n-((int)Math.pow(2, a)))+ 
            ....."+"+ String.valueOf(Math.pow(2, a));
    }
```

Comment: add some braces, and properly indentation.

Comment: I have edited the code a bit. Where do think I should add braces?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  First, supply a full running example.  Second, also describe what you *do* get from the program.

Comment: partition(600)returned :10-424+1024.0
while, partition (700) return : 10-324+1024
There is always a 10 at the beginning

Comment: When running your example with `System.out.println(partition(700))` I get `-324+1024`. Might the `10` be produced by some other printing?

Comment: Wow. This is a terrible application of recursion. The problem is not recursive in nature.  Also there's no need for `Math.pow()`, just use bit shifting for about 1000x performance improvement (not that performance is important here).  I hope the professor ends this lesson by saying "... and that's how NOT to tackle this problem. Now, here's the right way..."

Comment: Maybe you couldve taught me the right way instead of being rude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static String partition (int n)
{
            int a=0;
            if (n<=1)
                return String.valueOf(n);
            while ((int)Math.pow(2, a)<=n)
                a++;

            return partition(n-((int)Math.pow(2, a-1)))+ 
            ....."+"+ String.valueOf(Math.pow(2, a-1));
}
```

I have changed `a` to `a-1` in return part. It will work because once `pow(2,a)` is greater than `n`, we should use `a-1` instead of `a` as `pow(2,a-1)` is the greatest power of 2 less than `n`

Comment: Thats what I thought as well, but this is the result i got- 0+4+8+16+32+128+512
not - 1+2+8+16+64+512

Comment: @Lazim The result you got is correct. To proove you wrong: How can `1+2+8+16+64+512` ever be an even number, not to mention exactly `700`?

Comment: because the answer you are getting now sums up to 700 and the answer you are expecting doesn't

Comment: I havent realized. Thank you!